# What is the difference between Totipotent cells and Pluripotent cells?

Tags: cell-biology, terminology, embryology

I read the Wikipedia article about Cell Potency 
[(Article on Cell Potency)](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_potency&ved=0ahUKEwiPwMKusIjTAhVJRo8KHeNsBHkQFgglMAI&usg=AFQjCNGPp051CH5SP34hwZv0FH1UHCkMqA)

> Totipotency is the ability of a single cell to divide and produce all of the differentiated cells in an organism.

while pluripotency means

> a stem cell that has the potential to differentiate into any of the three germ layers: endoderm, mesoderm, or ectoderm.

I don't quite understand the difference, then, between a totipotent and a pluripotent cell.

Comment: You might be interested in [this](https://stemcell.ny.gov/faqs/what-difference-between-totipotent-pluripotent-and-multipotent).